# How to close window and reopen it, rerunning the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Any way to close the window and reopen it. Acting as a reset function?

Comment: What exactly are you talking about? GUI? Which lib?

Comment: Ah, pygame I see. Please include more details.

Comment: I guess your actual question is how to reset the game state?

Answer (score 0):

`pygame.quit()` closes the window and stops pygame. You can then call your program again and open a new window.